# How to fetch ldap server current timestamp?

Tags: java, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I am using unboundid api in our application, I want to fetch ldap server(OpenLDAP/Active Directory) current timestamp. Is it possible to fetch ldap server current timestamp using unboundid api?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: to fetch updated users list from openLDAP we check user modifyTimestamp attribute is greater than lastSyncDate. now we pass lastSyncDate from client site, but sometime ldap server date and client date is mismatch so we don't get expected output for ldap server. so we think to bring lastSyncDate from ldap server and save it into the database.

Comment: I don't know anything about unboundid-ldap-sdk, but to get a database's "last-changed-time" for openLDAP you can run this query: `ldapsearch -h directory-master0 -s base -b dc=mydomain,dc=org contextCSN`. For more information on the `contextCSN` do a web search for "openLDAP contextCSN".